# Cloud Formation: S3 linked to Lambda gives The ARN is not well formed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to use CloudFormation to deploy an S3 bucket that on `ObjectCreate` invokes a Lambda function.

Here are my resources:

```js
"ExampleFunction": {
            "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
            "Properties": {
                "Handler": "index.lambda_handler",
                "Code": {
                    "S3Bucket": "bucketname",
                    "S3Key": "something.zip"
                },
                "Runtime": "python3.6",
                "Role": {
                    "Fn::GetAtt": [
                        "LambdaExecutionRole",
                        "Arn"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "InputDataBucket": {
            "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
            "Properties": {
                "BucketName": "input-data",
                "NotificationConfiguration": {
                    "LambdaConfigurations": [
                        {
                            "Function": {
                                "Ref": "ExampleFunction"
                            },
                            "Event": "s3:ObjectCreated:*",
                            "Filter": {
                                "S3Key": {
                                    "Rules": [
                                        {
                                            "Name": "suffix",
                                            "Value": "zip"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "LambdaInvokePermission": {
            "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Permission",
            "Properties": {
                "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
                "FunctionName": {
                    "Fn::GetAtt": [
                        "ExampleFunction",
                        "Arn"
                    ]
                },
                "Principal": "s3.amazonaws.com",
                "SourceAccount": {
                    "Ref": "AWS::AccountId"
                },
                "SourceArn": {
                    "Fn::Join": [
                        ":",
                        [
                            "arn",
                            "aws",
                            "s3",
                            "",
                            "",
                            {
                                "Ref": "InputDataBucket"
                            }
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
```

I've tried to follow the documentation of the Notification Configuration, that says that there can be a circular dependency. However, if I follow the instructions I get the same error. Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket-notificationconfig.html

When I try to create the stack, the S3 always breaks it with error "The ARN is not well formed"

I've tried many things, but I always receive this same error.

Comment: Are you creating the S3 bucket and Lambda function alone in the initial CF create, then adding the NotificationConfiguration to the template and finally doing a CF update? Also, for the permission SourceArn, simply use "Fn::GetAtt": [ "InputDataBucket", "Arn" ].

Comment: There is also an IAM role, but nothing else. I've tried removing the NotificationConf and then updating it with it, but I still receive the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can get this to work as long as I know the S3 bucket name in advance (*mybucketname* below). If you don't know the bucket name in advance, then you can enhance this to request the bucket name as a stack parameter and it should still work. If you need the bucket name to be auto-generated (so you can't predict the name in advance) then this will not work and you'll have to go the create/update route.

Key thing here is to manually create the S3 bucket ARN from the known bucket name, rather than relying on `"Ref": "InputDataBucket"` to get the bucket name for you.

Also worth reading [this support article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/unable-validate-circular-dependency-cloudformation/).

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",

    "Description": "stackoverflow-48037497",

    "Resources" : {
        "ExampleFunction": {
            "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
            "Properties": {
                "Handler": "index.lambda_handler",
                "Code": {
                    "S3Bucket": "bucketname",
                    "S3Key": "something.zip"
                },
                "Runtime": "python3.6",
                "Role": {
                    "Fn::GetAtt": [
                        "LambdaExecutionRole",
                        "Arn"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "LambdaInvokePermission": {
            "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Permission",
            "DependsOn": [ "ExampleFunction" ],
            "Properties": {
                "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
                "FunctionName": {
                    "Fn::GetAtt": [
                        "ExampleFunction",
                        "Arn"
                    ]
                },
                "Principal": "s3.amazonaws.com",
                "SourceAccount": {
                    "Ref": "AWS::AccountId"
                },
                "SourceArn": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname"
            }
        },
        "InputDataBucket": {
            "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
            "DependsOn": [ "ExampleFunction", "LambdaInvokePermission" ],
            "Properties": {
                "BucketName": "mybucketname",
                "NotificationConfiguration": {
                    "LambdaConfigurations": [
                        {
                            "Function": { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "ExampleFunction", "Arn" ] },
                            "Event": "s3:ObjectCreated:*"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```